# Deploy website to drop folder on TFS build server

Tags: deployment, msbuild, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2012 on a build server to do continuous integration, and also builds for other environments. I am deploying a .net 4.0 webforms solution containing two websites and a console app to a build server and in the drop folder I get a _PublishedWebsites folder containing the deployment package for the custom configuration I have specified (ie not Debug or Release).  I get the correct .Web_Package for each website.

I am using the MSBuildArgumments setting in the build process as follows:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Development/p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0
```

Everything works well, but the team lead wants the actual deployment in the drop-folder and not the deployment package.

I have looked at the  [MS Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104%28VS.100%29.aspx) but it does not appear to help in my case.

I have tried creating a script, but I dont want to go into a huge series of powershell scripts, and I struggle with powershell anyway. I just cant get it to do what I want.

My question is: can this be done, and what is the best way of doing it? If it does mean creating a script then so be it (  perhaps one line for each object) - I am really having a hard time working out which direction I should be going in.

I thought something a script containing one line for each deployment -3 lines like this:

```
_PublishedWebsites/<project name>.Web_Package/<project name>.deploy.cmd /T: /M:<site> /U:<user> /P:<password>
```

But where to put the script and how to call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the solution as described in this blog post:

http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/automatic-config-transformations/

To get what I needed, I needed to change the project files of the projects to be deployed - adding this extra node at the top of each.csproj file

```
<Target Name="TransformConfigFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(TransformConfigFiles)'=='true'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DeleteAfterBuild Include="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Web.*.config" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)" Destination="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Web.config" />
    <Delete Files="@(DeleteAfterBuild)" />
  </Target>
```

and adding this switch to the MSBuildArguments in the build definition:

```
/p:TransformConfigFiles=true
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run my builds using the DeployOnBuild switch, my builds output two folders, one with the Package, and one with just all the website files (both under PublishedWebsites).  Is that not what you want?

I have:

> BuildDrop_PublishedWebsites\Website
>
> BuildDrop_PublishedWebsites\Website_Package

Comment: I get this already, but the website does not contain the transformed web.config - only the raw unprocessed ones (eg web.config, web.debug.config, web.development.config, web.test.config et al). The Website_Package however does contain the correct web.configs  - yes, if I could get the web.config to be correct, Id have a solution.

Comment: @JustTFS which is correct behaviour, what I want or what is happening?

Comment: what is happening, you would either deploy the package, or do some scripting to move around the files into the format that you want

Comment: As stated in the question, I need the transformed files in the drop folder. In a perfect world I would simply deploy, but my team lead (for some strange reason) does not trust the process.